# How can h5py dynamically save compound data types

Tags: python, hdf5, h5py

I'm trying to dynamically store compound datatype using `h5py`.The specific variable I'm using to test looks something like this:

```
(Pdb) mat_array
array([array([u'Sample Try:                   ', u"Mary Had A Little Lamb Named "], dtype='<U29'),
       array([u'Sample Try 2: ', u'Its Fleece Was'], dtype='<U14'),
       array([], dtype=float64)], dtype=object)
```

In the general case, I won't know what the dtypes of the various sub-matrices are, so I can't hard code anything. I would like to create an array of datatypes, which I could then put into a `create_dataset` call. But I've been unsuccessfully trying variations of

```
dt = np.dtype([(str(ctr), mat_array[ctr].dtype) for ctr in len(mat_array)])
ds = h5.create_dataset('temp_name', (len(dt),), dtype=dt)
ds[:] = mat_array
```

Does anyone know how I can take an arbitrary `numpy` array of a compound type and save it in HDF5 format using Python's `h5py` module, or if it's even possible?

Comment: You can save structured arrays.  But you can't save `object` dtypes.  Start with a relatively simple structured array, and trying saving and reading it.

Comment: @hpaulj - I would, but the problem is I'm trying to save an array produced by someone else's code. It basically has the form of the variable I'm testing for saving/reading